# How are C structure members accessed from memory at runtime?

Tags: c, struct

We have a structure in C say

```
struct info{
    int no;
    char first_name[20];
    char last_name[20];
    char status;
}
```

At runtime when we try to access these members by their name, say `info_var.no` or `info_var.first_name`, or we use a pointer to the structure, `info_ptr->no` or `info_ptr->first_name`, how are these individual members accessed?

I mean, the structure will be stored as member by member along with some necessary padding, but how does the runtime or maybe the compiler, if replacement happens at compile time, access those individual members by their name?

I know a lot of it is implementation dependent but if anybody could throw some light on any implementation or just give an overview it would be really nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing by a pointer or an object makes no difference, actually `info_ptr->no` is equivalent to `(*info_ptr).no`.

Actual member access is compiler-specific.

Say you have:

```
class A
{
public:
   char c;
   int x;
   A() {};
};
```

The following is the access code:

```
   A a;
004113BE  lea         ecx,[a] 
004113C1  call        A::A (4110E1h) 
   int y = a.x;
004113C6  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-8] 
004113C9  mov         dword ptr [y],eax
```

So the compiler, in this case, generates the binary knowing where `x` is stored in memory relative to `a` - that is 8 bytes into the `A` instance. This is because of padding.

EDIT: I just saw that the question is about C. Regardless, should be the same :).

Comment: Your code assumes that the object is local, which it probably won't be in most cases. Hence, your answer is wrong, especially if the pointer itself is a global variable. See my answer.

Comment: @Lindydancer I doubt that. You can't say "this is wrong" in a matter that is unspecified by the standard. I can write my own compiler that respects the standard and accesses memory in the way I described here. There's no one rule, I just pasted one of the possibilities. This code was generated by MSVC 2005 under a Win 32 platform with no optimization. And I specified that it is highly dependant on this.

Comment: It is wrong because you make the general statement "Accessing by a pointer or an object makes no difference". In this particular case it doesn't, but in the more common case, where the structure is a global variable, is certainly does make a difference. In fact, being a compiler developer, I would consider this to be a "frequently asked question", and I think it's really important to teach people that there normally is a big difference to the generated code.

Comment: @Lindydancer again, generated code is not part of the standard. `p->f` being translated to `(*p).f` is.

Comment: That is true, but that is not the question. Just because you can make the transform `p->f' to `(*p).f`, it does not mean that a pointer access like `(*p).f` would generate the same code as a direct access like `s.f`. In fact, the opposite is true.

Answer (score 5):

In C, the work is done by the compiler. It compiles the data members of the structs to memory offsets and applies them to the base address of the struct.

There is no dynamic lookup for variable names as in e.g Python

Answer (score 2):

There is a big difference between accessing a structure directly and via a pointer.

If you access it directly, the code will access the memory address directly, using a simplified assembler syntax, of a fictitious architecture. The examples below access the member `status`, which is stored at offset 44 in the structure:

```
MOVB  varno+44, reg2
```

On the other hand, if you would access it via a local pointer, the pointer would typically be stored in a register. So the code would look something like:

```
MOVB  44[reg1], reg2
```

The worst scenario is if the pointer itself is a global pointer, then the code must first read the value of the pointer:

```
MOVL  info_ptr, reg1
MOVB  44[reg1], reg2
```

The compiler can, in some cases, cache the pointer when performing multiple accesses. However, if the accesses are writes (to pointers or to characters), then compiler must assume that the pointer itself might have been changed and thus re-read it from memory.

I would strongly recommend using a one global structure, if your application only contains one.

Comment: Edit: Added that the assembler syntax is of a fictitious machine.

Answer (score 0):

Each field has a pre-determined offset from the start of the `struct`. The offset is determined at compile time. The machine code simply adds the field's offset to go from the address of the `struct` to the address of the field.

When you say "At runtime when we try to access these members by their name", it is important to note that *all* of the work having to do with the name is done at compile time.